# How can find out how much space my snapshots are taking in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am creating daily snapshots (backups) in `Amazon Ec2`, and I need to find out how much space the snapshots are taking so that I can remove them if they take up too much space. I have looked and I am unable to find what I need.

I know that its on S3, but I have not seen any `bucket` created here so that I can see that snapshot.

Also, is there a way to download a snapshot to my computer (where I can store it), and upload it when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots are persisted to S3, but are **not** stored in buckets owned by the user - so you won't be able to see them there.

To see how much space is being used by snapshots, you should be able to log in to the AWS Console through your web browser and see it under "Elastic Block Store", or if you've installed the command-line tools by running the [ec2-describe-snapshots command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSnapshots.html) you will see the following parameter returned:

```
volume-size

    The size of the volume
```

As for downloading your snapshots, it's possible with the non-Windows instance snapshots, but it's also quite involved. But [here's the instructions](http://preda.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/downloading-an-amazon-ec2-ami-to-local-drive/).

Comment: The the web console says 10GB infront all snapshots and i have 10. so does it mean that it is taking 100GB of space.

Comment: No it doesn't, sorry if I misunderstood your original question. Since they are storing the snapshots incrementally and probably applying some form of compression, you're not going to be able to see anything but the total for all snapshots (which appears on your monthly usage report), and this total won't be broken down. See http://serverfault.com/a/355290/100481

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick one liner

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids "1234567890" |  jq  ".Snapshots[].VolumeSize"  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}'
```